# How to extract the returne value of my function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I used this function to get the ratio width/height of a photo to assign automatic values of portrait or lanscape:

```
    var newimage = new Image();
    newimage.src = ImageDir; //Directory of my image
    newimage.onload = function ratio()
{
    var width = this.naturalWidth;
    var height = this.naturalHeight;
    var divi = (width/height);
    return divi.value;
}
```

```
alert(divi)
```

Will return the correct value, but I want to in corporate this code:

```
if (divi > 1) {
        node.getElementById("myImage"+"-"+nump).dataset.size = ("1600x1200");
    } else {
        node.getElementById("myImage"+"-"+nump).dataset.size = ("1200x1600");
}
```

I tried someting like this:

```
var newimage = new Image();
    newimage.src = ImageDir; //Directory of my image
    newimage.onload = function ratio()
{
    var width = this.naturalWidth;
    var height = this.naturalHeight;
    var divi = (width/height);
    if (divi > 1) {
        node.getElementById("myImage"+"-"+nump).dataset.size = ("1600x1200"); //nump is the number of repetitions the While loop as been in (for increments)
    } else {
        node.getElementById("myImage"+"-"+nump).dataset.size = ("1200x1600");
}
}
```

But the values of if and else won't output... They do if I put them out of the first function.
This is all in a While loop, so the divi variable will change everytime.

Can someone help me get that Divi value for my If condition?
Thank you!

Comment: `onload` happens asynchronously, you can't use the return value.

Comment: how could I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean they won't output? `dataset` values aren't rendered.

Comment: I do append them to a container id: container.appendChild(node); I just can't get the data divi out of the async function, I've been at least 6h on this problem, no one seem to have a good method